# Excel One-to-Many Table, Query Number of Rows Per ID

Tags: excel, one-to-many, pivot-table, vba

I have a one-to-many table in Excel, set up as shown in the picture. Each rid (ID) has many samples; each sample has a fixed number of properties (visit, visit type, etc).

[image]

I also have a pivot table set up to visualize the data:
[image]

Now, I need to filter/query my data to find all the IDs that have all 3 visit types: randomization And 30-week And delivery. (There are also additional queries I may need to do with each ID and its dependent objects)

Is this possible to do in Excel using advanced filters and pivot tables? Or do I need to write VBA scripts to process and organize this for me? (Using Excel 2010)

If a VBA script is best, should I use Find and FindNext to get all the samples that belong to an ID?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done in a bunch of ways; one would be to test for each criteria using a COUNTIFS function, and indicate whether any of these are 0. Like so (starting in cell H4 of your first tab there, dragged down):

```
=countifs(A:A,A4,C:C,"randomization")*countifs(A:A,A4,C:C,"30-week")*countifs(A:A,A4,C:C,"delivery")
```

If any of those testing types don't appear on the same row as the rid in column A, then the formula will simplify to 0.

To create a cleaner result, compare the function to 0, to show all rids where not all 3 are present; like so:

=0=countifs(A:A,A4,C:C,"randomization")*countifs(A:A,A4,C:C,"30-week")*countifs(A:A,A4,C:C,"delivery")

This will show TRUE wherever not all 3 tests were present for that rid. To only test for unique rids (will be a little cleaner; there are many ways to create a list of rids without duplicates, but this works too) :

```
=if(iserror(match(A4,$A$1:A3,0)),0=countifs(A:A,A4,C:C,"randomization")*countifs(A:A,A4,C:C,"30-week")*countifs(A:A,A4,C:C,"delivery"),"")
```

This only starts the formula if there is no match found for that particular rid, in any row above the current row.

Comment: Thanks, I see how this could work, but I can't get it to... I put the formula in the pivot table (2nd screenshot), but the countif only evaluated true for the row it was on. e.g. when the formula is next to "70115  randomization", randomization evaluates true. But it doesn't pick up if the ID has 2 more visit types (or even 1 more visit type)

Comment: Change your pivot table options to repeat the rows in the rid column, otherwise when Excel looks at those cells it sees blanks. Alternatively, put the formula on your raw data tab. Note that to do that you need to refer to column "F:F" instead of "C:C" in your formulas, as the locations of the "Visit Type" column are different between tabs.

Comment: @Grade-eh-bacon Perfect, it worked! A few minor modifications, so that I could run the formula once per ID and count the result: (1) Copy pivot table to new sheet. (2) Data Tab -> Advanced Filter -> Unique values in ID range (3) Add your formula to new column (except I used =0<> instead of =0=, so that it would return TRUE when value is NOT 0). (4) COUNTIF(range,"TRUE"). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Also, pre Excel 2010, you can Repeat Row Labels using the steps from the last answer here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/repeat-row-labels-in-a-pivottable/306a3c8f-d7c7-460b-b046-950646ac0427?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

If you just have 3 visit types, why not just perform a Count of ID, and if it is 3 it means it has the 3 visit types done. Something like

=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100,A1)=3,"Done","Pending")

I dont know.. if you have more than 3 visit types just let us know.

Comment: Yes, each ID could have more than 3 visit types. But I could see this working for some things.

Comment: This doesn't work as in the example table provided, some rid's have multiple visits of the same types.